# JasperServer - Crosstab scrolling issue/"feature"

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, crosstab

I am using jasperserver-pro 6.0.1.
Starting version 5.5 they have feature: Floating headers in table reports - In interactive reports, the headers remain visible when you scroll down through the report's rows.

I created the report with 2 crosstabs and published it to jasperserver.
Once I run it and try to scroll down headers become invisible (When there is one crosstab it works good).

Screen 1. 
[image]

When I scroll horizontaly one crosstab works good and for other I have bad scrolling

Screen 2. 
[image]

Is it system bug or is there any way to fix these issues?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Is it browser specific? If you have paid for support contact them first

Answer (score 0):

Check your **static text** **height and width** again, because there's overlap.